# Is there any difference between a one-time pad and a Vigenère cipher with a long key?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, vigenere

I've been browsing Wikipedia and stumbled on the article for the Vigenère cipher. I realized after seeing the example that it's quite similar to the one time pad, except with a short key repeated as the source of "random" information. That is, if you make the key longer than the plaintext, the two are the same.

Is that correct?

Comment: Apologies if my tags are off. I've only visited this place briefly before today.

Comment: Yes, Vigenère encryption with a key at least as long as the message is a one-time-pad.

Comment: As long as the key is used only one time.